# How can I search and replace an entire line in a text file?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

As part of an SSIS package that I am currently working on, I need to replace a where clause in the line of a text file.

I was thinking I'd use a Script Task with a `VB 2010` script to accomplish this, and I've been searching and have successfully found plenty of ways to search and replace a string, but I need to search for a string then replace the entire line containing it.

For example, the text file could contain:

```
Select= *

where= SDUPMJ>112310
```

I'd like to search just '`where=`' (since the actual clause will be different every time), and replace the entire line with '`where= SDUPMJ>112350`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it exists in a line by itself, use a streamreader.

Here's a sample of how I did it:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

Dim MyPath As String = "Path To Your Text File"

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Rdr As New StreamReader(MyPath)
    Dim ln As String
    Dim NewFile As New StringBuilder

    ln = Rdr.ReadLine

    Do Until ln Is Nothing

        If ln.StartsWith("where=") Then ln = "New Where Clause"
        NewFile.AppendLine(ln)
        ln = Rdr.ReadLine
    Loop

    Rdr.Close()

    File.WriteAllText(MyPath, NewFile.ToString)

End Sub
End Class
```

Hope this helps